# Use the switch statement for classes

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am new to the switch statement of javascript.

I have a big list of list items. Each item has its own class. For each list item something else should be done.

I make this switch code:

```
$('.nav-main li').click(function() {
    var item = this;

    switch (item) {
    case '.menu-intro':
        alert("test");
        break;

    case '.menu-intro-second':
        alert("test2");
        break;
    }
});
```

But the problem is: How can I check on the class names? When the nav-main li item hass class 'menu-intro'. Then something must happen. When the li item has class 'menu-intro-second'. Than another thing must happen.

How can I make this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try: $(item).attr('class'); ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
$('.nav-main li').click(function() {
    var item = this;

    switch ($(item).attr('class')) {
      // in case the the class of the element is only menu-intro
      case 'menu-intro':
        alert("test");
        break;
      // in case the the class of the element is only menu-intro-second
      // or in case the class is menu-intro-third
      case 'menu-intro-second':
      case 'menu-intro-third':
        alert("test3");
        break;
      // in case the the classes of the element is menu-intro and active
      case 'menu-intro active':
        alert("test4");
        break;
      // in all other cases...
      default:
        alert("default");
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: And can i do something with two classe. 

Like this. case 'menu-visie active, menu-imagine active':

When the classe is menu-visie active and menu-imagine active. Then there is the same thing happening

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this

```
 var item = this;
    switch($(item).attr('class')) {

    }
```